# integral matrix valued function

Tags: integration, matrices

Let $B, A\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be two matrices such that $B$ is symmetric and $A$ is normal matrix. I wonder whether there is an explicit formula (only on terms of $x, A$ and $B$)for the integral

$$I(x) := \int_0^x \exp(-tA)\, B\, \exp(tA) dt.$$

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: The Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff formalism , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula should shed some light on this.

Comment: How do you integrate a matrix?

Comment: I integrate the function $t \mapsto \exp(-tA) B \exp(t A)$ which is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and matrix-valued function.